# Current slide in materialize css carousel

Tags: html, css, materialize

How to get current slide in materializecss carousel component? I don't know how to link from carousel content to active class in li tags.

[For example i need get id element from div, where li class is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwZHH.png)

Comment: What have you tried? You should include the relevant parts of your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onCycleTo` callback function [option](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html#options):

```
 $('.carousel').carousel({
    duration: 100,
    indicators: true,
    onCycleTo: function(data) {
      //do what needs to be done in here ...
   }
});
```

The data param returns the `carousel-item` active Link Element. You could pass parameters with a `data-attribute` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current slides index using onCycleTo. Adding this answer since the previous answers don't show what to do within the function. Here's an example to get you started:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    onCycleTo: function (ele) {
      console.log(ele);
      console.log($(ele).index()); // the slide's index
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example with carousel thumbnail it does same thing you do like 
what i have done on that created a separate function which triggers (changes) slide by retrieving index key, and activating that slider to thumbnails carousel or main full screen one

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/hingoro/full/MvWZxd)

---

```
<!--html-->
 <div class="carousel carousel-slider grey">
    <a class="carousel-item" data-cindex="0" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" data-cindex="1" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/nature/2"></a>
  ...

//js
$('.carousel.thumbnails').carousel({
    dist: 0,
    padding: 20,
    onCycleTo: function(data){
        changeSlide( $(data).data('cindex'), '.carousel.carousel-slider');
    }
});

changeSlide = function(index, cl) {
   cl = (typeof cl == undefined) ? '.carousel.carousel-slide' : cl;
   $(cl).carousel('set', index);
}
```

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Visit:  https://jsfiddle.net/Balaram888/uj7sketo/

#### Carousel Index is:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/4"></a>
</div>


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel'),
            onCycleTo = function () {
                var activeIndicator = this.$indicators.find('.indicator-item.active');
                i = activeIndicator.index();

                document.getElementById("carouselIndex").innerHTML = i;

            },
            instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, { indicators: true, onCycleTo: onCycleTo });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in the materialize documentation
theres no "li" in carousel componets, its just a "div" with a bunch of "a" tag with the img in it.

```
<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
```

`

first you get the structure, then you just havet to put the initializacion in your javascript file

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

make sure the scripts load in the right way, otherwise it wont work

sorry for my english, let me know if it works.
good luck.

Comment: You're just showing how to use materializeCss' carousel feature. Definitly not what the question was about

Answer (score -3):

you should check http://materializecss.com/carousel.html for documentation

Comment: You should check the documentation before recommending it. At least for the last month there is nothing regarding active slide/item. I won't downvote though because I don't know if when you recommended it mentioned something useful for this question.